# setcookie doesn't set a cookie in IIS

Tags: php, setcookie

I have a PHP site, that I'm running locally in windows 10 (x64), using IIS (I installed PHP from the web platform installer).

The site works fine, but I'm trying to set a cookie, and well, nothing ever sets! I've tried a few combinations from the simplest:

`setcookie('test','test');`

To specifying more of the options:

`setcookie('test2', 'test',0,'/','.mydomain.com');`

Nothing happens - no Set-Cookie ever happens. I've also deployed this to an Azure website, and see the same behaviour.

Anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Have you checked the error logs?

Comment: @RowlandShaw - No, I'm not sure where they are, if they're enabled etc.. I'll dig around and see if I can find any

Answer (score 0):

Sigh. Shame on me, and thanks for @RowlandShaw for pointing me to the error log.

Had I know that the PHP error log eixsted, I would have seen these messages:

`Cannot modify header information - headers already sent`

Yup. Schoolboy error.